# How To Use DotNet HighChart In ASP.Net 5 / MVC 6

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm attempting to use the DotNet HighChart Library in an ASP.Net 5 / MVC 6 project to add charts to a page.

I've imported the library from NuGet and added the scipt references on the _layout view:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/highcharts/highcharts.js"></script>
```

I've defined a ViewModel class to hold the Chart:

```
public class IndexReportViewModel
{
    public Highcharts Chart { get; set; }
}
```

and created it and filled it with the stock example in the controller:

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        IndexReportViewModel ivm = new IndexReportViewModel();

        Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("chart")
            .SetXAxis(new XAxis
            {
                Categories = new[] { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" }
            })
            .SetSeries(new Series
            {
                Data = new Data(new object[] { 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4 })
            });

        ivm.Chart = chart;
        return View(ivm);
    }
```

The Controller has the required namespaces:

```
using DotNet.Highcharts;
using DotNet.Highcharts.Options;
using DotNet.Highcharts.Helpers;
```

Finally I've referenced it in the Index View:

```
@model TimeCheckBES.ViewModels.Reports.IndexReportViewModel

<p>My Chart</p>
   @Model.Chart
```

When the page loads it just seems to display the type of the HighCharts object, e.g.:

[image: HighCharts Fail]

Any ideas? I've tried:

- Adding the js references to the view itself rather than the _layout (I've checked the page in dev mode and they are loading).
- Calling the `@Model.Chart.ToHtmlString()` in the Index view.
- Not using a ViewModel and directly returning the chart object.

I think I must be missing something about the way js scripts work but can't think what it might be.

**EDIT**: Additional info

I've also added the namespaces directly to the view, although the compiler doesn't think they're necessary.

```
@using DotNet.Highcharts;
@using DotNet.Highcharts.Options;
@using DotNet.Highcharts.Helpers;
```

Comment: `@Html.Highsoft().Highcharts(Model.Chart)`?

Comment: Sorry - _IHTMLHelper does not contain a definition for 'HighCharts()'_

Comment: Have you added the `using` statement to your view?

Comment: Yes I have - plus _options_ and _helpers_.

Comment: But to the view? (you have just noted they are added to the controller)

Comment: Yep. In the view - declared with @ symbol.

Comment: `@using DotNet.Highcharts.Helpers;`?

Comment: Yes - have updated question to show this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I erased my previous answer. ASP.NET 5 / MVC 6 is not currently supported by Highcharts. So, you have two choices: Choice one you can wait for it them to update their stuff or two you can make a separate project with older framework and just link to it in your current project. http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/ here is the link to their codeplex site. This has examples if you want to try to make it work. By the way, I already tried and it was more work than it was worth.

You Also have the choice to use JQuery to get the same results.

JavaScript

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'area'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Historic and Estimated Worldwide Population Growth by Region'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: Wikipedia.org'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['1750', '1800', '1850', '1900', '1950', '1999', '2050'],
            tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
            title: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Billions'
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.value / 1000;
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            valueSuffix: ' millions'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                lineColor: '#666666',
                lineWidth: 1,
                marker: {
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    lineColor: '#666666'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Asia',
            data: [502, 635, 809, 947, 1402, 3634, 5268]
        }, {
            name: 'Africa',
            data: [106, 107, 111, 133, 221, 767, 1766]
        }, {
            name: 'Europe',
            data: [163, 203, 276, 408, 547, 729, 628]
        }, {
            name: 'America',
            data: [18, 31, 54, 156, 339, 818, 1201]
        }, {
            name: 'Oceania',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }]
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script async src="//jsfiddle.net/arx54ufv/embed/"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Hmm. In the above case the ViewModel is not doing anything.  Assigning it to the ViewModel's `Chart` and then calling `@Model.Chart` in the View as I've done above is the same in a round about way. I've tried it but it results in the same. I agree it seems to be returning the name of the type of the object rather than inserting the resulting html/js.